# can i use external placeholder in Email resource

Tags: digital-signature, docusignapi

I am trying to understand if it is possible to introduce external placeholder in Email Resource

For example, when i need the user to Acknowledge the receipt, i want the user to be re-directed to my page rather the default docusign URL.

I see that i can modify the "QuickURL". However I have many environment Like DEV / SIT /PROD.
So I am trying to see if i can make use of a placeholder outside so that i do not need to take a risk of wrongly modifying the EMAIL resource XML in every environment.

For example, i tried to see if I can make use of "Footer LINK" in the Branding. But no luck.

So i wanted to ask if there is a better way to achieve what i am trying to do here.

thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the Landing Pages area of the Branding configuration would be of use. Preferences > Account Administration > Branding > edit > Landing Pages. You can define where your user is re-directed based on the sate in which they've left the envelope (e.g. "finish later," "sign complete") after linking to DocuSign from e-mail.

There's a similar configuration for embedded signing, though, admittedly, we're having a problem with it right now.  Preferences > Account Administration > Features > Advanced > In session landing pages.